# Is there any way to change element color from left to right?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I've already done basic color animation using AnimationController and ColorTween. But it changes color from, like, every side of the element. And i want to change color from left to right (similar to progress bar, but i'm not allowed to use it). Is there any way to realize it with Tween animation or something else? Thanks in advance for your answers)
My code:

```
_controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 3), vsync: this)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {

        });
      });
    _colorAnimation = ColorTween(
      begin: Colors.deepOrange,
      end: ThemeHolder().accentColor
    ).animate(_controller);
```

Comment: "similar to progress bar, but i'm not allowed to use it".  Explain please.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz, I probably expressed incorrectly (english is not my first language). I meant, i should have only one element (button in my case) and it should change color on long press from left to right (just like progress indicator).

Comment: I was asking why you weren't allowed to use it.  Who is stopping you, and why?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz, customer said, that it should be a button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `stack` and a `container` goes from `0` to some value

```
Container(height:100,
width: _widthAnimation.value,
color:_colorAnimation.value,)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but my width should be static, so it will not work

Comment: Try to get the max width by surrounding the container by LayoutBuilder